# Not able get desired output after string parsing through regex

Tags: python, regex

```
input = 
6:/BENM/Gravity Exports/REM//INV: 3267/FEB20:65:ghgh
6:/BENM/Tabuler Trading/REM//IMP/2020-341

original_regex = 6:[A-Za-z0-9 \/\.\-:] - bt this is taking full string 6:/BENM/Gravity Exports/REM//INV: 3267/FEB20:65:ghgh

modified_regex_pattern = 6:[A-Za-z0-9 \/\.\-:]{1,}[\/-:]
```

In the first string i want output till
6:/BENM/Gravity Exports/REM//INV: 3267/FEB20
but its giving till :65:
Can anyone suggest better way to write this.
Example as below
https://regex101.com/r/pAduvy/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example use a capturing group with an optional part at the end to match the :digits:a-z part.

```
(6:[A-Za-z0-9 \/.:-]+?)(?::\d+:[a-z]+)?$
```

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `6:[A-Za-z0-9 \/.:-]+?` Match any of the listed in the character class as least as possible
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?::\d+:[a-z]+)?` optionally match the part at the end that you don't want to include
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/58Rq7W/1)

**Note** Not sure if intended, but the last part of your pattern `[\/-:]` denotes a range from ASCII range 47 - 58.

---

Or a more precise pattern to get the match only

```
6:/\w+/\w+ \w+/[A-Z]+//[A-Z]+(?:: \d+)?/[A-Z]*\d+(?:-\d+)?
```

- `6:/\w+/\w+`  Match 6 and 2 times `/` followed by 1+ word chars and a space
- `\w+/[A-Z]+//[A-Z]+` Match 1+ word chars, `/` and uppercase chars, `//` and again uppercase chars
- `(?:: \d+)?` Optionally match a space and 1+ digits
- `/[A-Z]*\d+` Match `/`, optional uppercase chars and 1+ digits
- `(?:-\d+)?` Optionally match `-` and 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tSBg7w/1)

Comment: Thanks , but cant hard code like this because there are cases where we may not have some character. string can be "/BENM/Tabuler Trading" just like this.  problem i m facing  with multiple :(colon), :6, :65: are tags in this string , when i m including : in regex , its taking :65:  tag also, i need data of tag 6 only ,that's the problem

Comment: @Navneet You can take from the first tag until the first occurrence of the next tag `^6:.*?(?=:\d|$)` https://regex101.com/r/wpikoU/1 Or if the tag is optional `^(?:^6:)?.*?(?=:\d|$)` https://regex101.com/r/pitdfR/1 If the `6` should not be hardcoded, you can use `\d+` instead to match 1+ digits.

Comment: @Navneet Any feedback?

Comment: sorry, couldn't update, code is getting complex, let me run through this regex with all strings, bt for sample its working, Thanks

Comment: Accepting this as of now , Thanks  @The fourth bird